# Will the Grails 1.3.5 framework support datasources plugin?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

What we need to do for using Datasources.groovy in our application?I am trying to install datasources plugin( grails install-plugin datasources in command prompt). But it is not working.

Please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: "It is not working" isn't enough information for anyone else to help you.  What have you tried so far, and exactly what error message or other symptoms are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on the Grails plugin repository

http://grails.org/plugin/datasources

> **Datasources Plugin** supported by SpringSource Tags : persistence
>   Latest : 0.5 Last Updated: 13 marzo 2010 **Grails version : 1.1.1 > ***

So you should be able to install it on your current application. Maybe its something wrong with the console install, try downloading it and installing it manually.

Good luck!